# <o:validateOneOrMore> shows error message for every row of dataTable

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, datatable, omnifaces

I'm having experience a problem with the omnifaces tag 
o:validateOneOrMore. I'm using this tag inside roweditor inside in a datatable. The problem is when the all the fields that I need filled are empty the validator works perfectly but shows the error message repetitively.

I'm using PF 5.1 and Omnifaces 1.14

the code :

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{matresUsuarioController.doEdit}" update=":f2:messages,:f3:dataTable" />

<p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{matresUsuarioController.doCancel}"       update=":f2:popup" />
<o:validateOneOrMore id="oneOrMore" components="ape1 ape2 nom nif" message=" Al menos alguno de los siguientes campos :{0} debe estar relleno." showMessageFor="@all"/>

...
<p:column sortBy="#{_matresUsuario.nombre}" filterBy="#{_matresUsuario.nombre}"
                filterMatchMode="contains">
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="#{msg['matresUsuario.nombre']}" />
</f:facet>
<p:cellEditor>
    <f:facet name="output">
       <h:outputText value="#{_matresUsuario.nombre}" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="input">
     <p:inputText id="nom" label="#{msg['matresUsuario.nombre']}"
                             value="#{_matresUsuario.nombre}"
                            style="width:100%"/>
    </f:facet>
</p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Try using `showMessageFor="@this"` instead of `showMessageFor="@all"`

Comment: Not works. I have the same problem.

Comment: I think the problem is that your components are found for each row in the data table (OF searches in the naming container: https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.4/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/component/validator/ValidateMultipleFields.java#L249 ).

Comment: Yes, Mi components are inside the row in a datatable. Is this a problem from my porpouses?

Comment: The validator should be placed inside a column (doesn't matter which, first one is okay), not outside. Fix it and retry.

Comment: I am having the same problem. The error message shows repeat 9 times. I tryed a <o:validateMultiple with custom validator function and the error is the same.

Comment: It works!!!! Many Thanks. You are very helpful for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342217/problems-with-proweditor-inside-datatable-paginate

Comment: I have a problem. The validator works correctly only in the first page of my dataTable. In the rest of pages not works correctly. Anyone can help me?